# nested routes is working different in rails 3.2 and rail 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 3.2 and having the following routes

```
resources :projects do  
  resources :assessments  
end
```

Now when I am using `project_assessment_path(@assessment)` in the view, it's assigning some `ID` as `project_id`(sample generated path `projects/1/assessments/2`)

I can't figure out how it's getting the `project_id`, but when I move to `Rails 4` it's giving me the error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches` which is quite expected. But I am wondering how it's working in `rails 3.2`

Comment: You have to change it to `project_assessment_path(@project, @assessment)`

Comment: I know the solution, but I want to know how it's working without passing the @project .

Comment: Would you provide the value of ```@assessment``` when from the first example, please? It should not be working if ```@assessment``` is a digit with Rails 3.2. It would work only if ```@assessment``` is a hash with ```{id: 2, project_id: 1}```. Generating urls in Rails generally is handled by the ```UrlFor``` module.